# Non-modular header error for a Top Shelf Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks, apple-tv, tvos

I am trying to write a Top Shelf extension for our tvOS app. We have a private Framework that handles all of our low level data code.

We are using Xcode 7.1 Beta 2.

A couple of notes about the framework…

- It uses only extension safe APIs.
- It works on iOS and tvOS.
- It is mostly written in Swift, but has some private C++ and Objective-C++ objects. A few of the Objective-C++ objects are accessible in Swift through an internal private modual (of course, there is no C++ in their headers). The *only* imports done in the headers files for these objects are are system libraries like Foundation and CoreGraphics. They are imported using the old `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` style because you can't use `@import Foundation;` in an Objective-C++ object.
- In our .modulemap, we import sqlite and use it in some Swift files.

Here is the module map file.

```
framework module MyFramework {  
    umbrella header "MyFramework.h"  
  header "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h"  

  module Private {  
  umbrella header "MyFramework_Private.h"  
  export *  
  }  

    export *  
    module * { export * }  
}
```

Here is "MyFramework_Private.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>  
#import <MyFramework/MyClass.h>  
#import <MyFramework/MyOtherClass.h>  
#import <MyFramework/AndSoOn.h>
```

The problem is that I cannot use MyFramework from a Top Shelf Extention. I get a compile error in "MyFramework_Private.h" for three files I import there (the `UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` works fine).

The error I'm getting is

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework.Private'
```

This error *only* happens when compiling the target for the Top Shelf extension. The MyFramework compiles (and runs) fine for an iOS app, an iOS Today Extension, and a tvOS app.

Should I file a radar on this or is there somthing obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a Xcode bug. Filed as rdar://22855945.